# MUI Toolpad not accessible on localhost

Tags: toolpad

On my Ubuntu 22 machine I followed the instructions at https://mui.com/toolpad/getting-started/installation/ but the browser says:

`Unable to connect Browser can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.`

How do I debug that? Thanks

Comment: Since this question was asked, Toolpad has changed direction and the installation steps have been heavily updated, see https://github.com/mui/mui-toolpad/discussions/1748